# WxPython Error with wx.BufferedPaintDC method - Invalid DC

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm currently updating a legacy application from Python 2.7.15 to Python 3.8.10. At the same time, I'm updating from wxPython version 2.8.12.1 to wxPython version 4.2.0.

I've used the 2to3 tool as well as done a lot of manual changes and the application is mostly running properly now. I have one major issue however, and it has to do with double-buffered drawing.

Specifically, in my onPaint() event handler, that has been bound to the EVT_PAINT event, I have the following code:

```
def onPaint(self,event):
    drawPanelSize = self.drawPanel.GetSize()
    self.bg_img = wx.Image('/background.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).Scale(drawPanelSize[0], 
    drawPanelSize[1])
    bmp = wx.bitmap(self.bg_img)
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.drawPanel, bmp, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)
```

There is more code above and below the code shown above, but this is the important area.

The problem that I am seeing is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./TestBench.py", line 1553, in onPaint
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.drawPanel, bmp, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion ""IsOk()"" failed at /tmp/pip-install-ewiqr929/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/gtk/dc.cpp(238) in DoStretchBlit(): invalid DC
```

Does anyone have any insight into what may be going wrong here? Like I said this code worked fine using and older version of Python and an older version of wxPython. I would also accept any advice on how to appropriately debug this.

Please let me know if more information is required. I've already verified that the arguments to the function are valid. (i.e. self.drawPanel, and bmp are created properly and are valid arguments to the BufferedPaintDC method)

Also keep in mind most of the application (including the UI widgets, which are relying on gtk) is working at this point.

Things to note about my environment:

ubuntu (20:04)

gtk-3 (3.24.2)

Python (3.8.10)
wxPython (4.2.0)

Comment: Maybe try https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.functions.html#wx.InitAllImageHandlers

Comment: What size are you getting for the panel? FWIW you could also just stop using buffered DC entirely, it's not needed with modern systems (definitely not with GTK 3).

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue using just a regular PaintDC.